# Need an event/confirmation if a openUrl type link is clicked in card in Azure bot node js

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service, web-chat

I am working on Microsoft bot framework using node js.

I can send a clickable link via text or card to the user and the bot needs to know when the link is clicked. Which event could be useful in this case?

Or if there is any other way to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a card to send a clickable link to user. **openUrl** action type specifies a URL to launch in the default browser.

The following code shows an example of openUrl action type in Node.js:

```
CardFactory.actions([
{
    type: 'openUrl',
    title: 'Tabs',
    value: 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/68135796/15969417'
}])
```

Further, among its activity CardAction types, you can use the below as per your need.

**1.** Action type **messageBack**: Sends a message and payload to the bot from the user who selected the button or tapped the card. Sends a separate message to the chat stream.

Properties

- **title:**   Appears as the button label.
- **displayText**(Optional): Used by the user in the chat stream when the action is performed. This text is not sent to your bot.
- **value:** Sent to your bot when the action is performed. You can encode
  context for the action, such as unique identifiers or a JSON object.
- **text:** Sent to your bot when the action is performed. Use this property
  to simplify bot development. Your code can check a single top-level
  property to dispatch bot logic.

The flexibility of messageBack means that your code cannot leave a visible user message in the history simply by not using displayText.

Example:

```
CardFactory.actions([
{
    type: 'messageBack',
    title: "My MessageBack button",
    displayText: "You clicked this button",
    text: "User just clicked the MessageBack button",
    value: {property: "propertyValue" }
}])
```

**2.** Action type **invoke**: Sends a message and payload to the bot from the user who selected the button or tapped the card. This message is not visible.

Properties

- **title:** Appears as the button label.
- **value:** This property can contain a string, a stringified JSON object, or a JSON object.

example of invoke action type in Node.js:

```
CardFactory.actions([
{
    type: "invoke",
    title: "B: Show me New Card",
    value: {
        option: "opt2"
    }
}])
```

Example of incoming invoke message
The top-level replyToId property contains the ID of the message that the card action came from. Use it if you want to update the message.

The following code shows an example of incoming invoke message: JSON

```
{
    "type": "invoke",
    "value": {
        "option": "opt2"
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-06-28T04:11:19.614Z",
    "localTimestamp": "2021-06-28T21:11:19.614-07:00",
    "id": "f:6894910823492785420",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1Eniglq0-uVL83xNB9GU6w_G5a4SZF0gcJLprZzhtEbel21G_5h-
    NgoprRw45mP0AXUIZVeqrsIHSYV4ntgfVJQ",
        "name": "karthik B"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "19:97b1ec61-45bf-453c-9059-6e8984e0cef4_8d88f59b-ae61-4300-bec0-caace7d28446@unq.gbl.spaces"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:8d88f59b-ae61-4300-bec0-caace7d28446",
        "name": "MyBot"
    },
    "entities": [
        {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "country": "US",
            "platform": "Web",
            "type": "clientInfo"
        }
    ],
    "channelData": {
        "channel": {
            "id": "19:dc5ba12695be4eb7bf457cad6b4709eb@thread.skype"
        },
        "team": {
            "id": "19:712c61d0ef384e5fa681ba90ca943398@thread.skype"
        },
        "tenant": {
            "id": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47"
        }
    },
    "replyToId": "1575667808184"
}
```

Example: After the link from option B is opened it returns to bot.

[image]

Additionally refer: [Adaptive Cards with invoke action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=javascript#adaptive-cards-with-invoke-action)

[Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json): To Sends a message and payload to the bot from the user who selected the button or tapped the card. Sends a separate message to the chat stream, message is visible to all conversation participants or to initiate OAuth flow.

Comment: @KarthikBhresh-MT, Thanks for your help. I need to send a third-party link with OpenUrl action type. Sending another action type would probably not open the link on browser. I am looking for an hyperlink to open a URL and the moment user clicks on the link, bot is notified for the same

Comment: yes, you can embed any URL, like in the first snip you can see this StakOverflow post link. The trick is to post the link on a button so that the response can be recorded.

Comment: I am sending the card with invoke action from one of the dialog steps and returned that step with 'return Dialog.EndOfTurn;'. Now expecting a click action response in the subsequent step, it does not reach there when user clicks on link. And typing anything it reaches to the next step